# How to create an rpm from a python exe?

Tags: python, redhat, rpm, packaging

I have a set of python exe that is created using pyinstaller. I want to package these exe in .rpm . How do I do this ? The reason I need to do this is to enable me to install the rpm on a red hat linux server
PS :  I don't have an option to switch from RPMs

Comment: `.exe` is for Windows not for Linux. You would have to install WINE (Windows Emulator) to run `.exe`. And Linux usually has preinstalled Python and it doesn't need converted with pyinstaller. It usually need to send `pip freeze > requerments.txt`  and later `pip install -r requerments.txt` to install all needed modules - and then script should run.

Comment: You will need to use pyinstaller if you cannot always control the versions of python on different systems , and the exe created by pyinstaller runs in linux production systems for me

Comment: @ZeeshanRafique “the exe created by pyinstaller runs in linux production systems for me” — That’s pretty much impossible. Are you talking about a Linux binary? `.exe` is the file extension for the Windows-based application format. Maybe it has an `.exe` file extension but that’s meaningless, unconventional and doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer fortunately after hours of trying , you can wrap all the exe in a tar in %install stage of rpm spec and pass the name of the tar file in %file . If you have a single exe , you do not need to create a tar